# How to solve a sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Given an array of numbers with only 2 unique numbers [3,5], sort the list without creating a new space. Try to solve it in Python, Thanks

Example 1:

Input: [3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3]

Output: [3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5]

Comment: I think it's possible in O(2), since there are two numbers. Ask your professor if that is acceptable.

Comment: sorry, I dont want to create a new space to solve it

Comment: How about just `print(sorted(input))` ?

Comment: Oh dear. It was a joke! You should really catch up on your big-O notation.

Answer (score 1):

```python
num = [3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3]

i = 0
j = len(num) - 1

while i < j:
    if num[i] == 3:
        i += 1
        continue
    if num[j] == 5:
        j -= 1
        continue
    num[i] = 3
    i += 1
    num[j] = 5
    j -= 1

print(num)
```

Comment: I've check it on my computer. It works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Define two new variables , `Count_3` and `Count_5`, then parse the list once and calculate the number of 3s in `Count_3` and for the 5s in `Count_5`
then for output just print `Count_3` 3s and `Count_5` 5s

Answer (score 0):

```
high = 5
low = 3

arr = [
    low,
    high,
    low,
    low,
    low,
    low,
    low,
    high,
    high,
    high,
    low,
]

cur = 0
index = 0

print(arr)

while (index < len(arr)):
    isLow = arr[index] == low
    arr[index] = high
    if (isLow):
        arr[cur] = low
        cur += 1
    index += 1

print(arr)
```

Or as someone else suggested, that I thought of after finishing this, it's most likely a better idea to first count all 3s and 5s instead of replacing as you go and simply make a new array knowing the counts.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with O(n). This is a solution if you know in advance what numbers you are looking for.

```py
numList = [3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 3]
looking = [3,5]

foundList = [[],[]]
for x in numList:
  if x == 3:
    foundList[0].append(x)
  elif x == 5:
    foundList[1].append(x)

finalList = foundList[0] + foundList[1]
```

Comment: OP was asking without creating "new space": you are creating a new list.